# java - LWJGL OBJ File Loader not working correctly

Tags: java, lwjgl

I've been trying to load an obj. file into my LWJGL application.  I have only the bare bones to get something to appear. My obj. is loading and displaying but its contorted/distorted.  I've tried it several ways and still not luck. This is the image I get.

[Resulting render of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVRoM.png)

Main.java

```
package Model;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.*;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Main {

    private Model m;
    private Vector3f location, rotation;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1200, 800));
            Display.setTitle("3D Game");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        location = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        rotation = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        try {
            m = Model.getModel("res/monkey.obj");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(30f, (float) (1200/800), 0.3f, 100);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            input();
            render();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void input() {
        boolean up = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W);
        boolean down = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S);
        boolean left = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A);
        boolean right = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D);
        boolean flyUp = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_E);
        boolean flyDown = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_Q);
        boolean speedUp = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT);
        boolean slowDown = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LCONTROL);
        float walkspeed = 0.15f;

        float mx = Mouse.getDX();
        float my = Mouse.getDY();
        mx *= 0.15f;
        my *= 0.15f;

        if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            rotation.y += mx;
            if (rotation.y > 360){
                rotation.y -= 360;
            }
            rotation.y += my;
            if (rotation.x > 85){
                rotation.x = 85;
            }
            if (rotation.x < -85){
                rotation.x = -85;
            }           
        }

        if(speedUp && !slowDown){
            walkspeed = 0.25f;
        }
        if(slowDown && !speedUp){
            walkspeed = 0.15f;
        }
        if(up && !down){
            float cz = (float) (walkspeed * 2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            float cx = (float) (walkspeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            location.z += cz;
            location.x -= cx;
        }
        if(down && !up){
            float cz = (float) (walkspeed * 2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            float cx = (float) (walkspeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            location.z -= cz;
            location.x += cx;
        }
        if(right && !left){
            float cz = (float) (walkspeed * 2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) + 90);
            float cx = (float) (walkspeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            location.z += cz;
            location.x -= cx;
        }
        if(left && !right){
            float cz = (float) (walkspeed * 2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)) + 90);
            float cx = (float) (walkspeed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)));
            location.z -= cz;
            location.x += cx;
        }
        if(flyUp && !flyDown){
            location.y -= walkspeed;
        }
        if(flyDown && !flyUp){
            location.y += walkspeed;
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glRotatef(rotation.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        glRotatef(rotation.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        glRotatef(rotation.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        glTranslatef(location.x, location.y, location.z);
        m.render();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
package Model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Model {
    public List<Vector3f> verts;
    public List<Vector3f> norms;
    public List<Face> faces;

    public static Model getModel(String s) throws IOException{
        return new Model(s);
    }

    private Model(String path) throws IOException{
        verts = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        norms = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        faces = new ArrayList<Face>();
        new ModelLoader(this, path);
    }

    public void render(){
//      glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (Face f : faces){
            Vector3f v1 = verts.get((int) f.verts.x -1);
            Vector3f n1 = verts.get((int) f.norms.x -1);
            Vector3f v2 = verts.get((int) f.verts.y -1);
            Vector3f n2 = verts.get((int) f.norms.y -1);
            Vector3f v3 = verts.get((int) f.verts.z -1);
            Vector3f n3 = verts.get((int) f.norms.z -1);
            glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
            glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
            glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
            glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
            glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
            glVertex3f(v2.x, v3.y, v3.z);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

ModelLoader.java

```
package Model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class ModelLoader {

    public ModelLoader(Model m, String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
        String line;
        while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("v ")){
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                Vector3f v = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
                m.verts.add(v);
            } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                Vector3f v = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
                m.norms.add(v);
            } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                float x1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]);
                float y1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]);
                float z1 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]);
                float x2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]); 
                float y2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]);
                float z2 = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]);
                Face f = new Face(new Vector3f(x2, y2, z2), new Vector3f(x1, y1, z1));
                m.faces.add(f);
            }
        }
        read.close();
    }
}
```

Face.java

```
package Model;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Face {

    public Vector3f norms, verts;

    public Face(Vector3f n, Vector3f v){
        this.norms = n;
        this.verts = v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact very close. If you look at the image of the monkey head,from blender I believe, it has most of the triangles being drawn. Half of the triangles are rendered. This leads me to believe that there is a problem with the order that indices for some of the faces are made. 
Secondly I have another idea. Since this has been exported from blender I would suggest making sure that you exported the monkey head with triangulation selected in the export options. This would ensure triangles to be created and not quads. Possibly you are extracting only the first three indices from the face line ("f ") and this would result in these triangles.

For the first possible fix I would recommend trying to disable face culling to see if it is fixed. If this does fix the model then the problem is withing the order of indices for faces.
Secondly I have just noticed that in your last glVertex3f of the render you have written v2 instead of v3 for the vertices x reference. This most likely is the problem.
Third if these do not work, then try exporting from blender again making sure to triangulate the model.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was indeed the triangulation and the one number was wrong.  I guess I was just looking at this for too long lol Again thank you so much!  

I have also recently started trying to get the blender materials to show up on the object as well as shadows.  If you have any advice as to how to approach this, I would be very grateful! again thank you!

Comment: Yes, I could help you with the shadows. I completed shadow mapping in the past and this was a rewarding experience. If you send me some sort of contact I could get you the information and some of my old code for it.